# ansible hashivault_list module missing

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault, ansible-module

I'm trying to get a list of secrets from hashivault using a simple Ansible playbook (I'm running the playbook from a Mac or a Linux CentOS 9):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - hashivault_list:
        secret: "ansible/"
      register: secrets
    - debug: 
        var=secrets
```

Unfortunately - I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'hashivault_list'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

`hashivault` module was installed:

```
    ansible-galaxy install hashivault
    Starting galaxy role install process
    - downloading role 'hashivault', owned by 
    - downloading role from https://github.com/mylocaldevstack/hashivault_ansible_role/archive/master.tar.gz
    - extracting hashivault to /Users/cosmin/.ansible/roles/hashivault
    - hashivault (master) was installed successfully
```

My ansible version:

```
    ansible [core 2.16.4]
      config file = /Volumes/Projects/ansible/playbooks/ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = ['/Volumes/Projects/ansible/playbooks/.library']
      ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.3.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
      ansible collection location = /Users/cosmin/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
      executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
      python version = 3.12.2 (main, Feb 20 2024, 04:30:04) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] (/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.3.0/libexec/bin/python)
      jinja version = 3.1.3
      libyaml = True`
    
    pip install ansible-modules-hashivault
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Requirement already satisfied: ansible-modules-hashivault in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (5.2.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: ansible-core>=2.12.0 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-modules-hashivault) (2.15.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: hvac>=1.2.1 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-modules-hashivault) (2.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-modules-hashivault) (2.31.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=3.0.0 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (3.1.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.1 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (6.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (41.0.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (23.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: resolvelib<1.1.0,>=0.5.3 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (1.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources<5.1,>=5.0 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (5.0.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from requests->ansible-modules-hashivault) (3.3.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from requests->ansible-modules-hashivault) (3.6)
    Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from requests->ansible-modules-hashivault) (1.26.18)
    Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from requests->ansible-modules-hashivault) (2024.2.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from jinja2>=3.0.0->ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (2.1.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from cryptography->ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (1.16.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Users/cosmin/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography->ansible-core>=2.12.0->ansible-modules-hashivault) (2.21)
```

I have installed also `hvac`, I tried to get it to work in a venv environment, changed to a Linux machine - and I'm getting the same error.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated...

Comment: What does ansible doc say that you have installed? `ansible-doc --list | grep -i hashi`

Comment: Looks like  you installed an old version of hashi vault.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. `pip install ansible-modules-hashivault` worked for me. It also installs `hvac` as a dependency automatically, so no need to install it by yourself. Could you maybe clean everything up and start again? To me it looks like you've did something additionally before or after installing the actual module. For example, `ansible-galaxy install hashivault` has nothing to do with the **module** you're referring to - it's a dummy **role** with no code abandoned 5 years ago.

Comment: Also, have you had a look into [Community.Hashi_Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/hashi_vault/index.html) collection and [Migrating from the `hashi_vault` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/hashi_vault/docsite/migration_hashi_vault_lookup.html)?